# Multiple entry Schengen visa date confusion

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, spain, netherlands

So, I have Schengen visa with the following dates:

FROM: 09-12-23
UNTIL: 07-12-24
NUMBER OF ENTRIES: MULT
DURATION OF STAY: 90

I have already travelled to Spain and came back to my country on following dates: 9th December 2023 to 21st December 2023.

Now my question is, can I enter Schengen countries again from: 20th May 2024 to 15th June 2024. What does the duration of stay mean here? Number of days I can stay from my first entry and after that it's invalid?

I am not sure if I need to reapply for a new visa again or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work)

Answer (score 7):

> What does the duration of stay mean here?

It means you may stay in the Schengen area for **90 days in any 180-day period**.

> following dates: 9th December 2023 to 21st December 2023.

Which means you spent 13 of the 90 days (77 days left).

> can I enter Schengen countries again from: 20th May 2024 to 15th June 2024.

You want to spend a further 27 days (out of the 77 days left - the time outside **does not count**) afterwhich you would still have around 59 days left, since the first 6 days of your first visit have expired (being more than 180 days in the past).

Since you have a multiple entry visa you can enter multiple times.

> I am not sure if I need to reapply for VISA again or not?

You do not need to apply for a new visa.

You can even plan a third trip as long as you leave (at the lastest) by 2024-12-07.